# exception __str__ returned non-string (type bytes) in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Trying to execute following methods where i get exception like **exception __str__ returned non-string (type bytes).**

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{}{:02d}:{:02d}:{:05.2f}".format(
        '-' if self.sign == -1 else '', self._deghour, self.minute, self.second)

def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

def __repr__(self):
    return u"RADecBase('{0}')".format(self)
```

Comment: When implementing the `__str__` magic method you MUST return a string (thus the error because you are return a utf-8 encoded string). So if you want to overload it that way you need to do something like `return str(unicode(self).encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about unicode vs bytes, and encoding vs decoding.

Encoding converts a (unicode) string into bytes. But the `__str__` method must return a string, not bytes. There is no need to encode there.

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self)
```

However I don't know how this is even working, as Python 3 doesn't define a `unicode` builtin and doesn't recognise the `__unicode__` method. You should just do this directly in `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{}{:02d}:{:02d}:{:05.2f}".format(
        '-' if self.sign == -1 else '', self._deghour, self.minute, self.second)
```